# Java best way to parse MongoDB file

Tags: java, mongodb

So, I read my `MongoDB` this way:

```
        mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        // Accessing the database
        MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("myDb");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("searchresults");

        // Getting the iterable object
        FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find();
        int i = 1;

        // Getting the iterator
        Iterator it = iterDoc.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
            i++;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, each line has several columns: `Title`, etc. So, when I iterate over `myDB`, i want to parse each line by its value instead of get all in one line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So the question is how to read a result rather than actually parsing a file? A hint: You're already looping over your results in your while loop. Put your `it.next()` call into a `Document` variable and see what kind of getters you can call on it. You can use that to investigate how to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: this it.next() get only Object

Comment: If you declare your iterator with generics by using `Iterator<Document>`, Java will see that a `Document` instance is expected when `it.next()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can try reading into a Document structure, then run another loop across each of the entries. This will give each value on its own line.

```
FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = database.getCollection("").find();
for(Document doc : iterDoc) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : doc.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " Value: " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

If you only want certain keys, use a projection in your find query

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fitting answer to your question, but i would look in to a concept thats called `Object-Document-Mapping (ODM)`. It simplifies some boilerplate code that you have to care about. A common library for MongoDB-ODM is called `Morphia` :)

Comment: So i did not understand what i have to do

Comment: You can use it.next() to iterate to the document entrySet. But i would use morphia :) just an advice